# Unable to run test case using detox

Tags: react-native, detox

[image]

I am facing the error below when running test case using detox.
I had all dependencies installed as part of it.

```
Can't find a simulator to match with " iPhone 6 ", run 'xcrun simctl list' to list your supported devices.

configuration="ios.sim.debug" artifactsLocation="artifacts/ios.sim.debug.2019-01-31 12-14-41Z" node_modules/.bin/jest "e2e" --config=e2e/config.json --maxWorkers=1 '--testNamePattern=^((?!:android:).)*$' 
detox[5864] INFO:  [DetoxServer.js] server listening on localhost:57598...
detox[5864] ERROR: [index.js/DETOX_INIT_ERROR] 
 Error: Can't find a simulator to match with " iPhone 6 ", run 'xcrun simctl list' to list your supported devices.
      It is advised to only state a device type, and not to state iOS version, e.g. "iPhone 7"
    at AppleSimUtils.findDevicesUDID (/Users/alok/Desktop/malliswari/accordion/node_modules/detox/src/devices/ios/AppleSimUtils.js:46:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: You shouldn't post errors as images, you should copy the error message and paste it. Please copy and paste the **whole** error message.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by setting the simulator in your `detox` config in your `package.json` to one that isn't on your system

```
"detox": {
    "configurations": {
      "ios.sim.debug": {
        "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.app",
        "build": "RN_SRC_EXT=e2e.js xcodebuild -workspace ios/myapp.xcworkspace -scheme myapp -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "name": "iPhone 7" // <- this is where you define your simulator
      }
    },
```

You should run `xcrun simctl list` in your terminal to see which simulators are available. Then use one of the available ones in your `detox` configuration. Chances are you should be able to change it to `"iPhone 7"` or `"iPhone 8"`

Comment: Iam using iPhone X as simulator and updated package.json as per it.

Comment: },
  "detox": {
    "configurations": {
      "ios.sim.debug": {
        "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/detoxtest.app",
        "build": "xcodebuild -project ios/detoxtest.xcodeproj -scheme detoxtest -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "name": "iPhone X"
      }
    },
    "test-runner": "jest"
  }
}

Comment: Facing below error                                                                                   
.Detox[28802] ERROR: [exec.js/EXEC_FAIL, #6] /bin/sh: /Users/alok/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3C26850F-B9D1-48D2-9491-224F76C0E69A/data/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.out: No such file or directory

Comment: Delete the `ios/build` folder and rebuild with detox using `detox build -c ios.sim.debug && detox test -c ios.sim.debug'`

Comment: Still facing the same issue.  Can you please help me out.

Comment: detox[13066] INFO:  [DetoxServer.js] server listening on localhost:55143...
 FAIL  e2e/firstTest.spec.js
  Example
    ✕ should have welcome screen (2ms)

  ● Example › should have welcome screen

    ChildProcessError: Command failed: /bin/cat /dev/null >/Users/alok/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3C26850F-B9D1-48D2-9491-224F76C0E69A/data/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.out 2>/Users/alok/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3C26850F-B9D1-48D2-9491-224F76C0E69A/data/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.err &&

Comment: You need to post your **full** error in your question. Comments are not the place for error messages as they are unformatted, difficult to read and usually truncated.

Comment: Example › should have welcome screen

    ReferenceError: device is not defined

      2 |   beforeEach(async () => {
      3 |     
    > 4 |     await device.reloadReactNative();
        |           ^
      5 |   });
      6 | 
      7 |   it('should have welcome screen', async () => {

      at Object.device (firstTest.spec.js:4:11)
      at tryCatch (../node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62:40)

Comment: detox[22383] ERROR: [exec.js/EXEC_FAIL, #6] "/bin/cat /dev/null >/Users/alok/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3C26850F-B9D1-48D2-9491-224F76C0E69A/data/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.out 2>/Users/alok/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3C26850F-B9D1-48D2-9491-224F76C0E69A/data/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.err && SIMCTL_CHILD_DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES="/Users/alok/Library/Detox/ios/97c1dcc1b30ebf51053e43d2bc79fd6e2e3018d1/Detox.framework/Detox" /usr/bin/xcrun simctl launch --stdout=/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.out --stderr=/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.err

Comment: Seriously I cannot help if you keep posting the error in the comments, You need to post it in the question, and it needs to be all of it

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is here

https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/1103

We need to upgrade **AppleSimUtils**. In case if you have issues in upgrading [check out here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56796772/problems-installing-applesimutils-using-homebrew)