# Problems installing applesimutils using Homebrew

Tags: homebrew, applesimutils

When trying to run the following commands:

```
brew tap wix/brew
brew install applesimutils
```

my `homebrew`  fails with the following:

```
Warning: Some installed formulae are not readable:
  applesimutils: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/wix/homebrew-brew/applesimutils.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected <<, expecting keyword_end
<<<<<<< HEAD
  ^
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/wix/homebrew-brew/applesimutils.rb:17: syntax error, unexpected ===, expecting keyword_end
=======
   ^
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/wix/homebrew-brew/applesimutils.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected >>, expecting keyword_end
>>>>>>> Detox Instruments 1.10.10110
  ^
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/wix/homebrew-brew/applesimutils.rb:23: unexpected fraction part after numeric literal
>>>>>>> Detox Instruments 1.10.10110
```

I'm running on

```
Environment:
  OS: macOS 10.14.5
  Node: 10.15.3
  Yarn: 1.16.0
  npm: 6.4.1
  Watchman: 4.9.0
  Xcode: Xcode 10.2.1 Build version 10E1001
  Android Studio: 3.4 AI-183.5429.30.34.5452501

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: 16.3.1 => 16.3.1
  react-native: ^0.55.4 => 0.55.4
```

I tried to do `brew doctor` and `brew cleanup` but still getting the same error.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Detox.

The solution for this issue is explained in the AppleSimUtils readme's [troubleshooting section](https://github.com/wix/AppleSimulatorUtils/blob/master/README.md#troubleshooting):

> If Homebrew complains about a conflict in the `wix/brew` tap, run `brew untap wix/brew && brew tap wix/brew` and try installing again

Comment: thanks for the help  now of course once you said it, it made sense. Thanks